# How to go about to designing an interface like the following

Tags: visual-c++

I have Visual C++ 6.0 and Visual C++ 2005 but have never programmed tried programming something like the picture here below... Can anyone tell me what would be involved in creating a similar GUI ? Do I use placeholders for the top toolbar and the same for the two sections (local computer and FTP servers) ?

http://www.flickr.com/photos/14402427@N02/3353415463/ 
http://www.internet-soft.com/ftpcomm.htm

Answer (score 1):

The lower portion would use a SplitterWindow, with various bits on the left and right to fill it in. The upper portion is one (or more) MenuStrips (I think that's the class name - I don't have VS open, and I'm feeling a bit lazy right now), with the menu displayed either as text, or as buttons. This presumes you're using VC++ 2005, and .NET 2.0 . I wouldn't recommend doing this with MFC and VC++ 6.0, especially as a newbie. It'll hurt...a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i would agree, trying to create a full app on your first project might be painful, why don't you instead look up on some open source ftp programs with source codes available?
then you can just practice your skill by modifying or adding some simple feature to it. and if it's useful you can contribute back your program to the community.

i think .net apps are relatively easy to find around the net these days. and i echo Harper & Charlie on that stick with .net for this one, you won't have to pull out as much hair from your crown.

just my two cents. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the feedback and suggestions. My opening paragraph was not very clear what I was trying to say is that I have not programmed something as complicated as this FTP client GUI as shown in the picture from the URL. The reason I wanted to give this GUI a try is because I use the very same FTP client and wanted to modify it somewhat. I'll try another FTP GUI something with source code or with a simple GUI.

Answer (score -2):

Oh, *man*, if you've never programmed at all, that ain't the way to get started.

Comment: With someone with 11.5k rep, I would expect an actual answer, not a rude comment like this.

Comment: It's not rude; it's helpful. I would have +1ed this answer, but it's really best as a comment to the question, as it's not an actual answer to the question.

Comment: I would consider it helpful, yes.  But it is said in a rude manner.  It would be greatly helpful explaining /why/ and how to actually start (giving references even).  Not just saying "you're wrong."

Comment: It's not rude, it's compassionate.  If someone walked in with a hammer and said "I think I'll hit myself in the head with this", would you tell him a ball-peen was better suited?